Distinct product grouping based on a set of columns with duplicate rows
THIS IS THE CURRENT STATE DATA:

THIS IS THE DESIRED FUTURE STATE:

Basically, the requirement is that, when the txn_type="dept" and txn_grp="store", from that txndate, within 183 days, if a sale happens, those should be considered.
So in the first row, for casemgr_id=99012 and casemgr_clntid=67891, the txndate is 9/12/23, for the txn_type="dept" and txn_grp="store", it should check the subsequent rows with txn_type="sales" and if those dates fall within 183 days, then it should consider those products ("M", "MP", "A", "MS"). If these products were sold, it should be updated in the prod_cat column and the corresponding sales and units should be updated.
So the casemgr_id=99012 sold the client=67891 the following products in the six month time frame: "M","MP","A","MS". These should be reflected in the same order, and the total sales and total units should be reflected.
If you look at the next example, the casemgr_id=99012, sold the client=95656 the following products: "M", "MS". So in the prod_cat column, the entries should be "MMS"
The sequence should always be "MMPAMS" depending on the produch that's sold.
Can someone help with the sql please?
select id1,med_id,txndate,txn_type,txn_grp,casemgr_id,casemgr_clnt,product,sales,
,sum(case when txn_typ='sales' and txn_grp='store' THEN sales/2 else 0 end) as total_sales_amt
,MAX(CASE WHEN product = 'M' THEN 'M' ELSE '' END)||
MAX(CASE WHEN product = 'MP' THEN 'MP' ELSE '' END)||
MAX(CASE WHEN product = 'A' THEN 'A' ELSE '' END)||
MAX(CASE WHEN product = 'MS' THEN 'MS' ELSE '' END) as prod_cat
,
,CASE WHEN (
           txndate-
          FIRST_VALUE(txndate) OVER
         (PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_clnt_id ORDER BY txndate)
         )  > 183
      OR (
           x.evnt_dt-
          FIRST_VALUE(x.evnt_dt) OVER
         (PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_clnt_id ORDER BY txndate)
         )  = 0
    THEN 'Consider'
    ELSE 'Do not consider'
  END AS status 

from tablename

The code above doesn't give me the expected output. Instead what I am looking for is, for example, if we take txntype=dept and txn_group=online, the txndate in row 10 is 6/13/24. The code should look for all sales (txn_type=sales) made by the same casemgr_id/casemgr_clnt_id combination (time period: 90 days prior and 180 days forward, so in the example I gave, if the case manager made any sales between March 13, 2024 to december 13, 2024, those should be considered) and the corresponding sales should be calculated and the products that they sold. So $200 in this case and prod_cat="MMS". This should be populated in the row with txn_type=dept. Right now, it doesn't do that.

Please don't upload images of data, you can edit and use markdown tables instead.

Look into lag and xmlagg.  Try building your query using those, come back and show what you've tried if you have specific questions.

@keithwalsh I tried but I wasn't able to edit. It doesn't allow me to submit markdown tables

Having "header" and "detail" in the same table is generally a poor data model. Maybe break it down: use a subquery (e.g. CTE) to extract "dept" rows and compute date range(s) to consider (use LAG if same casemgr/client can have multiple dept and you need to avoid overlap, else simple math).  Join back to the original table to aggregate sales and build the revised dept rows, and then perhaps UNION ALL the dept results and the original sales.  For the category tag I wouldn't bother with XMLAGG, just something like MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCT='M' THEN 'M' ELSE '' END) for each value, concatenated.

Thanks @Fred. I tried what you suggested and it doesn't give me the expected output. I edited the post with the code I tried. Can you please suggest what I should do to get the correct desired output?

@Andrew I did edit my original post with the code that I tried, which doesn't give me the expected output I'm looking for. Kindly help

Take a close look at your question. None of the initial data / desired results, the two English descriptions, and the SQL you supposedly tried (which is invalid and can't be executed) actually match each other. Please edit again or delete this question and post a new one that is consistent with what is actually needed.
